# Read small json files with declared schema from S3Bucket - Spark Performance Issue

Tags: json, scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark, jsonschema

I have huge number (35k) of small (16kb) json files stored on S3Bucket. I need to load them into DataFrame for futher processing, here is my code for extract:

```
        val jsonData = sqlContext.read.json("s3n://bucket/dir1/dir2")
            .where($"nod1.filter1"==="filterValue")
            .where($"nod2.subNode1.subSubNode2.created"(0)==="filterValue2")
```

I'm storing this data into temp table and use for futher operations (exploading nested structures into separate data frames)

```
    jsonData.registerTempTable("jsonData")
```

So now I have autogenerated schema for this deeply nested dataframe.

With above code I have terrible performance issues I presume its caused by not using sc.parallelize during bucket load, moreover I'm pretty sure that autogeneration of schema in read.json() method is taking a lot of time.

## Questions part:

How should my bucket load look like, to be more efficient and faster?
Is there any way to declare this schema in advance (I need to work around Case Class tuple problem thou) to avoid auto-generation?
Does filtering data during load make sense or I should simply load all and filter data after?

## Found so far:

```
    sqlContext.jsonRdd(rdd, schema)
```

It did the part with auto generated schema, but InteliJ screams about depreciated method, is there any alternative for it?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to case class, use a custom class that implements the Product interface, and then DataFrame will use the schema exposed by your class members without the case class constraints.  See in-line comment here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection

If your json is composed of unrooted fragments you could use s3distcp to group the files and concatenate them into fewer files.  Also try s3a protocol as it is better performance than s3n.